# Angular resource response interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I want to create a Custom Action on Resource, which will process the results received from the server.

```
angular.module('problem', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .factory('Abc', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('api/abc/:abcId', {abcId: '@id'}, {
            customQuery: {
              method: "GET",
              isArray: true,
              interceptor: {
                response: function (response) {
                  // some operations that manipulate data based od response
                  response.data = [5, 6]; // for simplifity
                  console.log("manipulation finished"); // log is saved
                  return response;
                }
              }
            }
          }
      );
    })
;
```

But when I use the Custom Action, I get the unmodified results instead of processed.
Here is the code showing the expected behavior (and in comments relevant errors):

```
describe('Abc', function () {
  beforeEach(module('problem'));
  var $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    })
  });

  it('should return converted array when customQuery called', inject(function (Abc) {
    $httpBackend
        .expectGET('api/abc')
        .respond([
          {id: 'uid1', name: 'name1'},
          {id: 'uid2', name: 'name2'},
          {id: 'uid3', name: 'name3'},
          {id: 'uid4', name: 'name4'}
        ]);

    var result = Abc.customQuery();
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(result.length).toBe(2); // fails with "Expected 4 to be 2."
    expect(result[0]).toBe(5);     // fails with "Expected { id : 'uid1', name : 'name1' } to be 5."
    expect(result[1]).toBe(6);     // fails with "Expected { id : 'uid2', name : 'name2' } to be 6."

  }));
});
```

Comment: The problem is currently out of date, but I think I should have returned a new response object with new data instead of tampering it. Propably `response.data` is immutable or even frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you need is to add a new transformResponse transformation, you can easily do that like this (remember to inject `$http`):

```
transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat([
    function (data, headersGetter) {
       return data.objects
    }
```

Difference is, `result` will be substituted by `response.resource`, while the return value of the interceptor is the value that is resolving `result.$promise`

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the "interceptor" idea!

in my opinion

```
response.data = [5, 6]; // for simplifity
return response;
```

should return a response-object, with a property-array "data", so

```
result.length;
```

should fail.

For manipulating the results of a resource response better use response.**resource** instead of response.data - there are the real REST objects (with CRUD methods)